# url can't be opened by click directly

Tags: html, openresty

there are two links on my page, the first url can only be opened by select open in new tab/window in right context menu.  Or the url can be pasted to browser address bar, then hit the enter. if i click that link directly, i got 403 forbidden page, and refresh doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

why?

Comment: Hi! There isn't really enough information here for us to do more than guess. Is this a page that you've created, and can show us the code for, or someone else's site you're trying to link to?

Comment: May be you haven't access to the server That why it is showing 403.